# What is the operating humidity of the Raspberry Camera Module V2

Tags: camera, picamera

I'm developing a project involving a Raspberry Cam that is likely to take pictures in a relatively high relative humidity context. However, I can control the relative humidity (the setting is in a laboratory) and I'd like to know up to which relative humidity I can work. 
I accept that a few pictures return errors due to humidity (so I'm not looking for a 99.99% success rate) but I'd like to have an idea of the range of relative humidity up to which I won't damage the raspberry cam.

I've been looking for the specs [on this website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/), but I can't find any data on the relative humidity resistance of the Cam V2.

Thank everyone for any help.

Comment: Comment, not an answer as it's not definitive, but I lived in Calgary, Alberta Canada where humidity is <10% rel, usually closer to zero. I then moved out (a couple of years ago) to extreme NW British Columbia Canada, where humidity was nearly as low, but temps were extremely low (-35c for a good portion of the winter). I now live in South-Central BC, Canada, in the Lakes District, and humidity here on average is 70-80%, daily, even in frigid weather. My cams don't balk. Again, I'm not vouching for anything, I'm stating experience. Got two Pis, two cameras outside, feeding to a central Pi.

Comment: ...the cameras are cheap, so are (especially) Pi-Zero-W. If you're experimenting, I'd suggest grabbing a few of each, and doing experimentation with them. By what you say about having a lab environment to test with, seems as though you may have access to hardware for playing with (that's great!).